Nextjs 14 and nodemailer POST work locally but give 405 in production
I have deployed my website on cloudflare.
I want to send an email with nodemailer. It works locally, but fails in production. In production it gives me "405 - method not allowed".
Initially I thought my env vriables are not set up correctly, however, I printed them and it seems they are with the correct values (in production!)
My project structure:

From my website/betatesting I call the following:
import { sendEmail } from '@/utils/send-email';

...
async function onSubmit(data: FormData, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      await sendEmail(data, setEmailSent, setError);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(true);
      console.error(error)
    } 
  }

Then on my sendEmail from @/utils/send-email:
import { FormData } from 'react';
import Error from 'next/error'
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';



    export async function sendEmail(data: FormData, setEmailSent, setError) {
      console.log("SEND EMAIL function: ", data); //prints correct values
      console.log("my email: ", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_EMAIL);   //prints correct values
      console.log("pass: ", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_PASSWORD); //prints correct values
      const apiEndpoint = '/api/email/';
      console.log("api endpoint: ", apiEndpoint); //prints correct values
    
      const res = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })     //FAILS HERE!!!!!!
      if(res.status === 200){
        setEmailSent(true);
      }else{
        setError(true);
      }
    }

My app/api/email/route.ts file:
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import Mail from 'nodemailer/lib/mailer';

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("MY WEBSITE DOES NOT REACH THIS PART IN PRODUCTION")
  const { email, name, message, android, ios } = await request.json();
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions: Mail.Options = {
    from: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_EMAIL,
    to: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_EMAIL,
    // cc: email, (uncomment this line if you want to send a copy to the sender)
    subject: `Message from ${name} (${email})`,
    text: `Message content ${message}, ANDROID:  ${android}, IOS: ${ios}`,
  };

  const sendMailPromise = () =>
    new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          resolve('Email sent');
        } else {
          reject(err.message);
        }
      });
    });

  try {
    await sendMailPromise();
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Email sent' });
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

Again, it works locally, it fails in production. Any ideas, why or how to fix it, much appreciated!
